# How to erase or disable boot info from drives

Tags: boot, grub, bios

I have a computer with 5 hard drives, but when I stop the BIOS to look at my choices, it has 14 choices for booting (Including a DVD, but let's ignore that).  These are choices in BIOS, not in GRUB -- so each one takes me to a GRUB menu, and they are not all identical.  Since I'm in the midst of cleaning up a disaster I caused a while ago, and just on general principles, I'd like to just erase the boot info and grub loader from all but the first two drives.

Some of these drives are formatted GPT, some MBR.  There are Windows 10 and Xubuntu systems.  Apparently there are UEFI and standard boot views among the 14. All this reflects its history, which began in 2002.  Motherboards and other things have changed since, but a lot of data is still there.

I am tempted to just clobber the first 512 bytes on most of the drives, but I'm (a) not sure that's enough, and (b) not sure it's entirely safe.

So what's best practice for cleaning this up?

Comment: First thing I do is turn off os-prober in Ubuntu. And then only copy into 40_custom the few entries that I really want. Speeds kernel updates as os-prober does not have to scan every partition for a system. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2392441&p=13816046#post13816046
Using 40_custom & Custom menu
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/CustomMenus If UEFI boot entries, you can use efibootmgr -b https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198221/cloning-ssd-also-cloned-boot-options & see `man efibootmgr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overwriting the first 512 bytes on the drive will certainly render a BIOS-bootable disk non-bootable. It will also destroy the MBR partition table, so any MBR-partitioned disks will appear empty and unpartitioned after that. So **don't do it to any disk whose partitions you'll wish to keep.**

If a disk is MBR-partitioned but UEFI-bootable (i.e. it has a FAT-type filesystem on it with the partition type code set to 0xef, and that partition contains a file at path `\EFI\BOOT\BOOTx64.efi` for 64-bit x86 systems), overwriting a partition table is **overkill**: all you need to do to make the disk non-UEFI-bootable is to *delete that file or rename it to something else*.

For GPT-partitioned UEFI-bootable disks, overwriting the first 512 bytes does nothing at all: some disk partitioning tools might note that the protective MBR seems to have been damaged, and most likely will offer to fix it automatically or as a side effect of doing anything else to the GPT partition table with no trouble at all.

The extra boot choices in BIOS menus are most likely obsolete UEFI boot variables: as oldfred suggested in the comments, use `sudo efibootmgr -v` in Linux to view them, identify the `BootXXXX` number of the obsolete entries, then use `sudo efibootmgr -B -b XXXX` to delete them.

Making a BIOS-bootable disk unbootable without destroying the partition table is actually kind of tricky: the easiest way I know is a little utility named `ms-sys`, which can write many types of BIOS Master Boot Records and Partition Boot Records... including the humble "non-bootable disk" Master Boot Record.

Unfortunately that utility does not seem to be available in the package repositories of modern Ubuntu. Its source code is available at https://sourceforge.net/projects/ms-sys/ (or an older version is mirrored at https://github.com/pbatard/ms-sys if you don't like SourceForge). If you have `gcc`, `make` and the common application development libraries installed, you should be able to build it with:

```
<download the source code package>
tar xvf xvf ms-sys-2.8.0.tar.gz
cd ms-sys-2.8.0
make && sudo make install
```

If successful, you should now have the tool at `/usr/local/bin/ms-sys` and its man page at `/usr/local/man/man1/ms-sys.1` (viewable with a simple `man ms-sys`).

To make a BIOS-bootable disk `/dev/sdX` unbootable using `ms-sys`:

```
sudo ms-sys --mbrzero /dev/sdX
```

The description of the `--mbrzero` option on the man page is:

> ### -z, --mbrzero
>
> Write an empty (zeroed, non-bootable) master boot record to device. Zeroes all bytes except the partition map and signature id (bytes 01be-01ff).  Similar to the empty DOS partition table that fdisk creates.

The fact that it avoids overwriting the partition table (called "partition map" for some reason) and the disk signature bytes are the important part.

Comment: Thanks to @telcoM and @oldfred; I had never heard of ms-sys, or even efibootmgr.  Big help!